# tkinter sticky=N+W Error: global name 'N' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, global

I am making a tkinter GUI but I am not getting why this error shows. Also, I am having trouble in understanding initializing Frame. Is that related to the error, maybe? I am still new to Python and need to understand more on how it works. Sorry, if the mistake will be basic, I am having a troubled mind. Your help will be appreciated. This is the code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import string

class QueryInterface(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, master):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
    self.master.geometry("400x300+400+200")
    self.master.title("Thug Client-Side Honeypot")
    self.master.resizable(width = False, height = False)

    self.inputLabel = tk.Label(self, text = "Input arguments and URL:", font = "Calibri 11")
    self.inputLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, padx = 5, packy = 10, sticky = N+W)

    self.frame.pack()

def main():
  root = tk.Tk()
  app = QueryInterface(root)
  app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "QueryInterface.py", line 71, in <module>
    main()
  File "QueryInterface.py", line 67, in main
    app = QueryInterface(root)
  File "QueryInterface.py", line 17, in __init__
     self.inputLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, padx = 5, packy = 10, sticky = N+W)
 NameError: global name 'N' is not defined
```

Comment: You import Tkinter as "tk", so everything exported by the module needs to be prefixed by `tk` (eg: `tk.N`). This isn't a tkinter problem, this is how all python modules work.

Comment: @BryanOakley thanks for the note

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the error mentions, the problem is that you are referencing a variable N (as well as W) which are not defined.

These are variables defined in Tkinter, so you could do tk.N and tk.W, or alternatively just use the strings that those variables define, e.g.:

```
 self.inputLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, padx = 5, pady = 10, sticky = 'nw')
```

There are a couple of other issues that were preventing the code from running. You were creating a separate member Frame inside your QueryInterface which already inherits from Frame, and packing that.

This code runs.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class QueryInterface(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, master):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.master.geometry("400x300+400+200")
    self.master.title("Thug Client-Side Honeypot")
    self.master.resizable(width = False, height = False)
    self.inputLabel = tk.Label(self, text = "Input arguments and URL:", font = "Calibri 11")
    self.inputLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, padx = 5, pady = 10, sticky = 'nw')
    self.pack()

def main():
  root = tk.Tk()
  app = QueryInterface(root)
  app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: File "QueryInterface.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.inputLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, padx = 5, packy = 10, sticky = tk.N)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1985, in grid_configure
    + self._options(cnf, kw))
_tkinter.TclError: bad option "-packy": must be -column, -columnspan, -in, -ipadx, -ipady, -padx, -pady, -row, -rowspan, or -sticky

Comment: I believe that kwarg should by pady (packy isn't a valid arg). I've updated the answer.

Comment: I still just don't get why I had that error since I was able to run it before. But after editing the initialization of the frame and class, I was getting that. Sorry, i am slow in getting this.

Comment: Thanks for the packy, tsk tsk, I didn't see that coming. Thanks

Comment: thanks for noting about the frame initialization. I get it now, thanks!